# How to get information of the job when print job has arrived?

Tags: macos, printing, cups

I am trying to find out printer jobs information in Mac OS and I have got this by using CUPS library. Now I want to get the information of new job when print job has arrived. Does anyone know that how to programmatically get the information of the job when print job has arrived using CUPS library or any other? Or how to monitor print job queue?